# How to access the remote parent branch of my local branch with GitPython or similar library?

Tags: git, gitpython

I want to be able to create a pre-push git hook that merges the remote parent branch of my local branch into my local branch so that I can resolve any potential merge conflicts locally rather than wait for Stash to tell me there is a merge conflict.

I have Googled this but can't find exactly what I require. Any advice would be appreciated.

Thanks

Answer (score 2):

According to [the documentation](http://gitpython.readthedocs.org/en/stable/reference.html#git.refs.head.Head.tracking_branch), you want to use the `tracking_branch` attribute.  I haven't used the gitpython library myself so I cannot go into more detail.

Comment: I don't think that returns the parent though, but only the remote tracking branch of my local branch.

Comment: That's all git has.  What exactly are you thinking of that you're calling "parent", that's different from the remote-tracking branch?

Comment: I see the confusion. By "parent", I'm referring to the ancestor branch. In my case, it's the master branch and my local branch is a "project" branch. So I want to merge the remote master branch into my local branch so I can identify any merge conflicts.

Comment: Git does not record this information.  In some cases you can intuit it from the graph.  In others, there's enough information in the reflogs.  But it's not generally do-able and I doubt there's anything built in to gitpython to attempt either method.  (But once you know that you want `master` you can simply look up `master`'s remote-tracking branch, and then do a merge by commit ID into an anonymous branch, for instance, just for discovering conflicts.)